# Как составить запрос который вернёт JSON массив в PL/SQL таблицу?

Tags: sql, json, oracle, plsql

Есть следующий код:

```
SELECT tab.* from (
    SELECT '{  
        "name":"John",
        "age":30,
        "cars": [
            {"name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang"]},
            {"name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5"]},
            {"name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda"]}]}' data FROM dual),
JSON_TABLE (data, '$' columns (
    "Name" varchar2 (16) path '$.name', 
    "Age" varchar2 (16) path '$.age', 
    "Car" varchar2 (16) path '$.cars[*].name')) tab
/
```

Он возвращает такую таблицу:

```
Name             Age              Car             
---------------- ---------------- ----------------
John             30               NULL
```

Но хотел бы получить все имена из массива `cars`:

```
Name             Age              Car             
---------------- ---------------- ----------------
John             30               Ford
John             30               BMW
John             30               Fiat
```

Как можно получить такой вывод?

Попробовал заменить в `$.cars[*]` `*` индексами (1,2,3), но тогда выводит только одну строку.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How do you run a query that returns a JSON array into a PL/SQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62762735) от участника [@Manuel Vázquez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13879721/manuel-v%c3%a1zquez)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/62762735

Answer (score 2):

В этом случае надо воспользоваться [NESTED PATH](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/function-JSON_TABLE.html#GUID-37CBD672-5B0A-4FAB-A3AF-144E76686BD5) клаузой. Вот так:

```
select t.* from (
    SELECT '{  
        "name":"John",
        "age":30,
        "cars": [
            {"name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang"]},
            {"name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5"]},
            {"name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda"]}]}' data FROM dual),
json_table (data, '$' columns (
    "Name" varchar2 (16) path '$.name', 
    "Age"  varchar2 (16) path '$.age', 
    nested path '$.cars[*]' columns ( 
        "Car" varchar2(16) path '$.name'))) t
/
```

Результат:

```
Name             Age              Car             
---------------- ---------------- ----------------
John             30               Ford            
John             30               BMW             
John             30               Fiat
```